# Showing all results after filter on map, but with different color

Tags: filter, maps

### Description

In general, our mobile app provides users with the ability to book classes in gyms/studios, etc. So, one of the main functions of the app is to search for some training to attend. In list/map representations of classes, the user can filter them by time/sport/type etc.

---

### Question

Now, when the user filters classes on the map, we hide irrelevant results. Sometimes it leads some users to confusion, that hidden gyms don't exist anymore. As a solution, we are thinking about showing all results but setting disabled colors to irrelevant ones.

**Questions:**

1. Is it bad practice to show irrelevant results as disabled ones on the map?
2. Have you ever seen the same logic anywhere else?

---

P.S: That's my first question here and I'm a product manager, not a UX designer. If you want any clarification or additional information I will be pleased to share it with you :)

Thanks in advance!

---

### Update 1.1

How design looks right now. All gyms/studios without filters and with filter only gyms

**1. All venues**

[image: all]

**2. Only gyms**

[image: gyms]

Comment: It sounds like the main focus is on locations, not the activities in the locations. I can see the complexity coming from different use cases, e.g. a) I want to know what this gym/studio has to offer or b) I want Yoga near me and don't care in the first place which gym/studio. I'd think the first design iteration should keep the main purpose/use case of the app in mind and then be tested. https://urbansportsclub.com/en might have faced the same challenge.

Comment: @greenforest Thank you, we have the same product as USC, but in different countries :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some folks feel strongly about not using disabled items, but I believe there is a place for them as long as the user isn't entirely in the dark about WHY they can't take any interaction.

Honestly, based on your description I think it would be far more confusing to me as a user to see a map - which normally does not change in its base layout - suddenly have buildings hidden that were previously there.

More context and detail on your situation and perhaps an example of your map could help quite a bit in understanding the situation more, but from what you've described it might just be a shift in emphasis that is needed. **Instead of "disabling" the structures on the map that are not relevant to the user's filters, HIGHLIGHT the ones that ARE relevant**. The map itself should likely not change much, and if you focus on drawing attention to the buildings the user CAN interact with, there is less confusion about the ones they cannot (or that will have less relevant results).

This is my first thought based on your description - if you can share more detail I am sure there will be more insight the community can give you.

(and if you need more info about what I am describing feel free to comment back here and I will check in later).

Comment: highlighting actually sounds like a great idea!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, good one!

Comment: upd: added screenshots